# Python writing to CSV formatting issue

Tags: python, csv, parsing

I am having troubles with writing data to CSV being formatted correctly. The data is anime tv shows, and includes certain data such as title, genre and synopsis. After parsing through the data from the API call, it all writes correctly to the CSV except for the genres and synopsis. If an anime has several genres, only the first seems to be wrapped in " ", and the rest become integrated with and start from the synopsis.

Parse function:

```
def parse_data(data):
    try: 
        
        # Genre parse
        genres_list = data['genres']
        genres = ', '.join(genre['name'] for genre in genres_list)
        print(genres)
        
        # Studio parse
        studio_name = "unknown"
        studio_parse = str(data.get('studios'))
        match = re.search(r"'name':\s*'([^']*)'", studio_parse)
        if match:
            studio_name = match.group(1)
        else:
            None
        
        # Synopsis parse
        synopsis_dirty = data['synopsis']
        synopsis = re.sub(r"\(Source: [^\)]+\)", "", synopsis_dirty).strip()
        synopsis = re.sub(r'\[Written by MAL Rewrite\]', '', synopsis).strip()

        
        details = str(data['id']) + ',' + data['title'].encode('utf-8').decode('cp1252', 'replace') + ',' + data['start_date'] + ',' + str(data['mean']) + ',' + str(data['rank']) + ',' + str(data['popularity']) + ',' + str(data['num_episodes']) + ',' + data['rating'] +  ',' + studio_name + ',' + genres + ',' + synopsis.encode('utf-8').decode('cp1252', 'replace')
        split_data = re.split(r"[,]", details)
        
        return split_data
```

Dictionary format:

```
def parsed_data_to_dict(data):
    try:
        dict = {
            "id" :  data[0],
            "title" : data[1].encode('utf-8').decode('cp1252', 'replace'),
            "start-date" : data[2],
            "mean"  : data[3],
            "rank"  : data[4],
            "popularity" : data[5],
            "num_episodes" : data[6],
            "rating" : data[7],
            "studio" : data[8],
            "genres" : data[9],
            "synopsis" : ''.join(data[10:]).encode('utf-8').decode('cp1251', 'replace')
        }
```

```
Expected CSV:

"8","Bouken Ou Beet","2004-09-30","6.93","4426","5274","52","pg","Toei Animation","Adventure, Fantasy, Shounen, Supernatural", "It is the dark century and the people are suffering under the rule of the devil Vandel who is able to manipulate monsters."
```

```
Actual CSV:

"8","Bouken Ou Beet","2004-09-30","6.93","4426","5274","52","pg","Toei Animation","Adventure"," Fantasy Shounen SupernaturalIt is the dark century and the people are suffering under the rule of the devil Vandel who is able to manipulate monsters."
```

Comment: Where it this code does it write a CSV?  Make a [mcve] (<- *please read the link*).  Parsing and writing CSV files yourself is error prone.  Use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.htm#module-csv) module.

Answer (score 1):

You create comma-separated strings manually to use them as csv raws.
This approach is error prone, especially since your strings include commas. You always need to carefully combine "" and '' strings.

I suggest you using the [csv standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
split_data = re.split(r"[,]", details)
```

does split at all `,` characters. Before that line you already have `data` which is dictionary and thus is fit for use with [`csv.DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) (part of standard library), it allows strings to hold `,` and will also deal with string which contain `"`, consider following example

```
import csv
with open('names.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=['uno', 'dos', 'tres'])
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'uno': 'simple', 'dos': 'with , comma', 'tres': 'with " quote'})
```

will give file `names.csv` with following content

```
uno,dos,tres
simple,"with , comma","with "" quote"
```